# Make BoxDecoration image faded/transparent

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the following snippet of code and I would like to make the image faded such that it does not interfere with other items in the container.
Is there a filter that could accomplish this?

```
child: new Card(
  child: new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
        image: new DecorationImage(
          image: new ExactAssetImage('lib/images/pic1.jpg'),
             )
           )
     )
   )
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You could give your `DecorationImage` a `ColorFilter` to make the background image grey (use a `saturation` color filter) or semi transparent (use a `dstATop` color filter).

[image: screenshot]

Code for this example is below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text('Grey Example'),
    ),
    body: new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        new Card(
          child: new Container(
            child: new Text(
              'Hello world',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
              image: new DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
                image: new NetworkImage(
                  'http://www.allwhitebackground.com/images/2/2582-190x190.jpg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

The `Opacity` widget is another option.

You could also pre apply the effect to the asset.

Comment: The Opacity widget seems to affect the contents of the whole container which is not quite what I wanted. I have gone with pre applying the effect. How would I use ColorFilter to make it transparent? setting the color to grey seems to override any effect blendmode might have. thanks.

Comment: For Opacity, you could use a Stack to put something on top of your image. I updated my answer to provide a code sample for the ColorFilter approach.

Comment: P.S. For those who wonder whether the performance is OK or not (since images and opacity are both resource-heavy things), here is what I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64726479/4619958

Answer (score 44):

You can simply use

```
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```

Answer (score 27):

For those who wonder *whether the **performance** is OK or not* (since images and opacity are both resource-heavy things), here is my dig into the doc and the source code and the answer.

**Conclusion: Use `DecorationImage(colorFilter: ...)` will be *as fast as* what official doc suggests. (But `Opacity`, `ColorFilter` widgets are not)**

Firstly, we should *not* use `Opacity` or `ColorFilter` widget since it may trigger `saveLayer` and is expensive (by [official doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices#apply-effects-only-when-needed)).

Instead, we [should](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices#apply-effects-only-when-needed)

> Use the Opacity widget only when necessary. See the Transparent image section in the Opacity API page for an example of applying opacity directly to an image, which is faster than using the Opacity widget.

Looking at the suggested [method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html#transparent-image), we see the following sample:

```
Image.network(
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/assets-for-api-docs/master/packages/diagrams/assets/blend_mode_destination.jpeg',
  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate
)
```

Now, the problem is, is the highly-voted answer, i.e. the following code, as fast as what the official doc mentions for `Image` widget?

```
Container(
  child: Text('hi'),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
    image: new DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
      image: new NetworkImage(
        'http://www.allwhitebackground.com/images/2/2582-190x190.jpg',
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

To answer this, let us look at `Image.network`'s source. This constructor will directly fill in the `colorBlendMode` field of `Image`.

In `Image`'s `build`, it will be *directly* passed to `RawImage`'s `colorBlendMode` field.

Then, `RawImage` will create `RenderImage` (which is a RenderObject) and updates `RenderImage._colorBlendMode`.

Next, notice how RenderImage handles this -

```
  BlendMode? _colorBlendMode;
  set colorBlendMode(BlendMode? value) {
    if (value == _colorBlendMode)
      return;
    _colorBlendMode = value;
    _updateColorFilter();
    markNeedsPaint();
  }

  ...

  /// If non-null, this color is blended with each image pixel using [colorBlendMode].
  Color? get color => _color;
  Color? _color;
  set color(Color? value) {
    if (value == _color)
      return;
    _color = value;
    _updateColorFilter();
    markNeedsPaint();
  }

  ...

  ColorFilter? _colorFilter;
  void _updateColorFilter() {
    if (_color == null)
      _colorFilter = null;
    else
      _colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(_color!, _colorBlendMode ?? BlendMode.srcIn);
  }
```

A more dig into `rendering/image.dart` will show that, `colorBlendMode` (and `_colorBlendMode` will not be used in other places except to create this `_colorFilter`.

Thus, we know the two arguments of `Image.network` will finally go into `RenderImage._colorFilter`.

Indeed, that `_colorFilter` will be used in `RenderImage.paint` as

```
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    ...
    paintImage(
      canvas: context.canvas,
      rect: offset & size,
      image: _image!,
      colorFilter: _colorFilter,
      ...
    );
  }
```

So we know it! It will be used in `paintImage` which communicates with native methods. No wonder it is faster than `Opacity`.

No go back to our `DecorationImage`. Inside `painting/decoration_image.dart`, we see `DecorationImagePainter`:

```
class DecorationImagePainter {
  DecorationImagePainter._(this._details, ...);

  final DecorationImage _details;

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, Path? clipPath, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    ...
    paintImage(
      canvas: canvas,
      rect: rect,
      image: _image!.image,
      colorFilter: _details.colorFilter,
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Hey, that is exactly the same!

Answer (score 18):

You can simply use a Stack widget and use a simple coloured container above the image with reduced opacity.

EG : [image]

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

        import './page2.dart';
        import './page3.dart';
        import './page4.dart';

        void main() {
          debugPaintSizeEnabled = true ;
          return runApp(Start());
        }

        class Start extends StatelessWidget {

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            // TODO: implement build
            return MaterialApp(
              title: 'InIt',
              home: Builder(builder: (context) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    return Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return Page2();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Scaffold(
                    body: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[

                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage('images/page1.jpg'),
                                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.19),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'LETS BE PRODUCTIVE TODAY',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 50.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'bold',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              RawMaterialButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                constraints:
                                    BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 10.0, width: 10.0),
                                shape: CircleBorder(),
                                fillColor: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              Page2call(),
                              Page3call(),
                              Page4call(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            );
          }
        }

        class Page2call extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            // TODO: implement build
            return RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                return Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Page2();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 10.0, width: 10.0),
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              fillColor: Colors.white,
            );
          }
        }

        class Page3call extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            // TODO: implement build
            return RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                return Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Page3();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 10.0, width: 10.0),
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              fillColor: Colors.white,
            );
          }
        }

        class Page4call extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            // TODO: implement build
            return RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                return Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Page4();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 10.0, width: 10.0),
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              fillColor: Colors.white,
            );
          }
        }
```

This is a fully practically implemented example. You can increase the opacity over here 
to make the background even more faded, the fourth argument is for opacity:

```
Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.19),
         ),
```

This method also gives u the ability to chose the colour of the fading filter.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Opacity class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html).
A widget that makes its child partially transparent.

```
Opacity(
  opacity: 0.5,
  child: Image.asset('images/lion.png'),
)
```

Comment: this is not what the thread wants. He wants a method to affect `DecorationImage`

Comment: but this is what we came looking for