# Making an Image widget disabled / grayed out

Tags: flutter

I have a bunch of Image widgets which when in a disabled state, should look grayed out.

Is there a way to alter an existing image make it look disabled / grayed out?

I want to avoid having both an enabled image asset and a disabled image asset increasing the overall APK size instead of having the single asset.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Set the widget as the child of a container, and add foregroundDecoration like this:

```
Container(
  foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.grey,
    backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.saturation,
  ),
  child: child,
)
```

-- Update:
Based on [this new video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7Cll22Dno8) from flutter team, there is another widget for this.
The code is basically the same, and it is like this:

```
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
    Colors.grey,
    BlendMode.saturation,
  ),
  child: child,
)
```

But I still prefer the method using Container forgroundDecoration, since container gives you more flexibilities in the same place.

Comment: can I adjust the grey value for lighter grey?

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to apply the filter over the background of the image too. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @TinMan check the video link I added in the update section. Use the color parameter in the image.Asset widget.

Comment: @stanliu sure, you can change the colour to whatever you want. :)

Comment: @SinaSeirafi Unfortunately, ColorFiltered still doesn't handle transparency :(

Comment: @TinMan no, not ColorFiltered, I suggest you try the default image widget and add the color there. Like this:
Image.asset( 
  "URL",
  color: Colors.white,
)
I recently tested it and it works fine.

Comment: OP asked to disable it as well, so if there are buttons, one could additionally wrap `child` by an `IgnorePointer(ignore:true, child:child)`

Answer (score 29):

According flutter documentation of ColorFiltered you can use ColorFilter.matrix [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ColorFilter/ColorFilter.matrix.html) like this:

```
const ColorFilter greyscale = ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
  0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
  0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
  0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
  0,      0,      0,      1, 0,
]);

ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: greyscale,
  child: child,
);
```

In this case ColorFilter will ignore transparent areas of your images.

Comment: For transparent images, this is the simplest approach ([for now at least](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12990)).

Comment: How do you lerp this to zero effect so we can lerp saturated to desaturated?

Answer (score 14):

If your child is a .png image, flutter will render it with a grey background if you put `Colors.grey`. Using the same color of your widget background you will have a perfect disabled image

```
ColorFiltered(
    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
        Colors.white,
        BlendMode.saturation,
    ),
    child: child,
)
```

If you want to change the color of your image when user clicks it, you can do this:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => {
        setState((){
            _active = !_active;
        })
    },
    child: ColorFiltered(
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(                                       
            _active ? Colors.transparent : Colors.white,                                                         
            BlendMode.saturation,

        ),
        child: Image(
            image: Image.asset("assets/test.png").image
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 12):

I adapted  Mark O'Sullivan post and created a general purpose widget:

To use it:

```
text = Text("Hellow World");
GrayedOut(text);
```

or

```
GrayedOut(text, grayedOut: true);
```

And the class

```
class GrayedOut extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool grayedOut;

  GrayedOut(this.child, {this.grayedOut = true});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return grayedOut ? new Opacity(opacity: 0.3, child: child) : child;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not what OP asked, instead it just wraps an Opacity widget.
If you apply it to a colored image, that won't be grayed out but merely faded.

Answer (score 8):

From my own personal experiences I've found combining a color filter along with Opacity works well in giving a disabled state to an Image.

[image]

Shown above is an example of one of my enabled images.

[image]

Shown above is what that image looks like looks like whenever you apply a color filter and add Opacity widget to your image.

For you to implement something similar you would need this code:

```
  new Material(
      elevation: 2.0,
      child: new Opacity(
        opacity: 0.3,
        child: new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: new Image.asset("assets/<your icon>", fit: BoxFit.cover, color: Colors.grey),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            border: new Border.all(
              width: 2.0, color: const Color(0x40000000)),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(5.0)
            )
          )
        )
      )
  );
```

Answer (score 5):

This widget implements what [the Google Flutter engineer @dnfield](https://github.com/dnfield) said on [this Flutter GitHub issue](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/290), which works with images with transparent background.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class GrayscaleColorFiltered extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const GrayscaleColorFiltered({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ColorFiltered(
      colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
        0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0, //
        0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
        0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
      ]),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it perfectly avoids to mess up transparency of child.

Comment: Glad you think that, @wangpan! :·)

Answer (score 4):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

---

**Code:**

```dart
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5), // 0 = Colored, 1 = Black & White
    BlendMode.saturation,
  ),
  child: Image.asset(
    'chocolate_image',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913537/6618622)

Comment: This is the best answer of 2023

Answer (score 2):

I created a Widget based on Marks answer above:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DisabledRenderer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool enabled;
  final double padding;
  final double boxWidth;
  final Color boxColor;
  final double boxRadius;

  DisabledRenderer(
      {@required this.child,
      @required this.enabled,
      this.padding = 2,
      this.boxWidth = 2,
      this.boxColor = Colors.white,
      this.boxRadius = 5.0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Material(
        elevation: 2.0,
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.3,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
            child: child,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: boxWidth, color: boxColor),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(boxRadius)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

In use it looks like that:

```
DisabledRenderer(enabled: false, child: Icon(MdiIcons()['speedometer'],);
```

The enable bool is usually used with a StreamBuilder to listen to a model event.
How to do that please search for Flutter Bloc pattern and StreamBuilder

If you need a version which supports streams (bloc pattern) then use this one:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DisabledRenderer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool enabled;
  final Stream enableStream;
  final double padding;
  final bool showBorder;
  final double boxWidth;
  final Color boxColor;
  final double boxRadius;

  DisabledRenderer(
      {@required this.child,
      this.enabled,
      this.enableStream,
      this.showBorder = true,
      this.padding = 2,
      this.boxWidth = 2,
      this.boxColor = Colors.white,
      this.boxRadius = 5.0}) {
    //one or the other, not both
    assert((enableStream != null && enabled == null) ||
        (enableStream == null && enabled != null));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Material(
        elevation: 2.0,
        child: enableStream != null
            ? StreamBuilder<bool>(
                initialData: false,
                stream: enableStream,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot enabled) {
                  return enabled.hasData
                      ? _renderEnabledDisabledState(enabled.data)
                      : Container();
                },
              )
            : _renderEnabledDisabledState(enabled),
      );

  Widget _renderEnabledDisabledState(bool enabled) {
    return IgnorePointer(
      ignoring: !enabled,
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.3,
        child: showBorder
            ? Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
                child: child,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: boxWidth, color: boxColor),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(boxRadius)),
                ),
              )
            : child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is how you would use it:

````
DisabledRenderer(
                 showBorder: false,
                 enableStream: BlocProvider.of(context)
                                      .bluetooth
                                      .isConnected
                                      .stream,
                 child: YourWidget(),
    ```
````

Comment: I do not mind if people vote down a solution. It would be nice if you could state briefly what the problem is and we can all learn from it because we make an honest effort here. Thank you.

Comment: Your widget looks coupled to your project. Why a stream is present in your class? And your code is not abstracting the complexity of your project. BTW: the downvote is not mine.

Comment: Its not coupled to my project. Its a generic examples . The enable state can come either from a enable bool or from a stream<bool>. streams are often used in Flutter / dart projects. The last example shows how I use it in my project but the widget itself is generic.

Comment: You are right, your component is not really coupled. It just feels strange to see a Stream of booleans in this kind of component, but I see you exposed a simple boolean as well.

Comment: If you use streams in your model you can directly consume it no StreamBuilder etc. Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

To configure a custom grey color (or any other color) to a transparent image:

```dart
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(
    Colors.grey, // or any other color
    BlendMode.srcATop,
  ),
  child: MyImage(),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

However it is not possible directly. For runtime grayscale you can use a dart [image package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image) with flutter.
Load your images with dart image package, apply grayscale function, read the bytes from grayscale image and use it with `Image.memory` widget of flutter.

You can just get bytes without applying grayscale for a coloured image.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done using alpha, which can create effect of disabled. This trick works for dark and light theme too because it inherits from parent. I have used cardColor, you can choose any theme and apply the color.

```
Theme.of(context).cardColor.withAlpha(180)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using `BackDropFilter` In below code I am **bluring widget + adding grayscale**. This solution will work even for dialog

```
BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.compose(
      outer: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 6, sigmaY: 6);,
      inner: const ColorFilter.mode(
        Colors.grey,
        BlendMode.saturation,
      ),
    ),
    child:AnyWidget(),
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

used this

```
class GrayscaleColorFiltered extends StatelessWidget {
   final Widget child;

    const GrayscaleColorFiltered({Key? key, required this.child}) : 
  super(key: key);

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.grey, 
 BlendMode.saturation),
  child: child,
);
}
```

its work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you use [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package, you can do it like this

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: '${imgurl}',
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  color: Colors.grey,
  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.color,
  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
  placeholder: (context, url) => loadingIndicator,
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(
    Icons.broken_image,
    size: 100,
    color: Colors.grey,
  ),
)
```