# How to apply dynamic thresholding (convert to B/W) to a greyscal image in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, image, image-processing, flutter

I am currently developing an app where I need to apply dynamic [thresholding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)) to a grey scale image.

=======================================================================

I am new to both **thresholds** and **flutter** as such my current understanding is:

1. Get all the pixel values from the grey scale image which is going to be within the range (0-255)
2. Set a threshold e.g. 110 with the range
3. Convert any value less than the threshold to 0 (BLACK)
4. Convert any value more than the threshold to 255 (WHITE)
5. Display the modified array of pixel values as an Image widget

Now I have come across several packages:

1. [Image](https://pub.dev/packages/image)
2. [Bitmap](https://pub.dev/packages/bitmap)
3. [Extended Image](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image)

I am not sure exactly what approach I should take with Flutter to apply thresholding to a grey scale image where I can change the threshold value using a slider widget.

[GREY SCALE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOu02.jpg) ----> Threshold: 110 ----> [B/W IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBYWY.png)

Please do let me know, if I need to clarify any part of my question or if it is too vague. I will try my best to further your understanding.

HIGHLY APPRECIATE ANY HELP! Cheers!

Comment: you are changing the pixels to either black if less than 110 and white if greater than 110 which will convert the pixels to either black or white as you showed us in the image. You can see this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851690/making-an-image-widget-disabled-grayed-out). i believe it is what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making an Image widget disabled / grayed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851690/making-an-image-widget-disabled-grayed-out)

Comment: @MohammadAssemNasser my image is already greyed out. My requirement is to be to able to make it black and white based on a threshold which is a value between 0 and 255. How do I change the individual pixel values of the image based on the threshold?

Answer (score 1):

```
     Future<Widget> binarizeImage() async
  {
    var image1 = await _picker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery);
    // Load the image into Flutter
    img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(File(image1!.path).readAsBytesSync());

    print("Image data  before ${image!.data.toString()}");

    // Set the threshold value
    final threshold = 4286578687;

    // Iterate over each pixel in the image and apply the threshold
    for (var x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < image.height; y++) {
        final pixel = image.getPixel(x, y);
        if (pixel <= threshold) {
          image.setPixel(x, y, 4278190080); // Black
        } else {
          image.setPixel(x, y, 4294967295); // White
        }
      }
    }

    print("Image data ${image.data.toString()}");

    return Image.memory(
      Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(image)),
    );
  }
```

Comment: threshold 4286578687 and the ones commented as BLACK and WHITE are the pixel int values of the colors in "Uint32"

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as BLUECALF but for image version 4

```
Future<File> binarizeImage({
  required File imageFile,
  required StencilThreshold stencilThreshold,
}) async {
  // Load the image into Flutter
  Image? image = decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());

  // add alpha channel, as image could be jpg
  image = image!.convert(numChannels: 4);

  // Iterate over each pixel in the image and apply the threshold
  for (final pixel in image) {
    if (pixel.luminanceNormalized <= stencilThreshold.luminance) {
      pixel.setRgba(0, 0, 0, 0); // Transparent
    } else {
      pixel.setRgba(255, 255, 255, 255); // White
    }
  }

  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;

  File newFile = File(
    '$appDocPath/${DateTime.now().millisecond}_${imageFile.name}',
  );
  await newFile.writeAsBytes(Uint8List.fromList(encodePng(image)));

  return newFile;
}



enum StencilThreshold {
  level1(
    name: 'Level 1',
    luminance: .15,
  ),
  level2(
    name: 'Level 2',
    luminance: .2,
  ),
  level3(
    name: 'Level 3',
    luminance: .25,
  ),
  level4(
    name: 'Level 4',
    luminance: .3,
  ),
  level5(
    name: 'Level 5',
    luminance: .4,
  ),
  level6(
    name: 'Level 6',
    luminance: .5,
  ),
  level7(
    name: 'Level 7',
    luminance: .6,
  ),
  level8(
    name: 'Level 8',
    luminance: .7,
  ),
  level9(
    name: 'Level 9',
    luminance: .8,
  );

  final String name;
  final double luminance;

  const StencilThreshold({
    required this.name,
    required this.luminance,
  });
}
```

[image]