# Flutter PageView - animate color so current item is colored, the rest is black and white

Tags: flutter

I would like to replicate the Uber cal selector with a Flutter pageview, and animate the color of the CircleAvatar , so the current selected is colored, and the rest is black and white.
Here is an image https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://i.pinimg.com/originals/60/ea/31/60ea3157bbd1253b7309be0bc1f05786.gif&imgrefurl=https://www.pinterest.com/pin/346636502562604170/&docid=G13bqqL0wbOisM&tbnid=uWqijKyoLSabaM&vet=1&w=400&h=700&source=sh/x/im

Any tips how to best achieve this effect?

Related answer on greying out images [Making an Image widget disabled / grayed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851690/making-an-image-widget-disabled-grayed-out)

Comment: Simply how about use 'AnimatedPhysicalModel' widget of 'ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget class'? 
'https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPhysicalModel-class.html'

Comment: check `ColorFiltered` class and `ColorFilter.matrix` constructor

Comment: I could not get it to work with PageController as it is hard to get the currentPage, plus often it is empty at startup, sometimes it not an int. Lots of edgecases, so I let it go. Here is a nice overview of using Colorfiltered https://medium.com/@samarth_agarwal/turn-images-to-grayscale-in-flutter-the-colorfiltered-widget-16de44cf8045