# Adjust the brightness of images in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, image-processing

Does anyone know how to adjust the brightness of an image asset in flutter? I currently have a background image and I wanted to add some brightness to the image for now. Could I get any assistance?

```
 Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'assets/images/image.png',
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

Use a `ColoredBox` over your image in a `Stack`:

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: [
      Image.asset('chocolate_image', fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ColoredBox(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5) // 0: Light, 1: Dark
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

You can also use [this `ColorFiltered` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67674207/6618622) for more customizations.