# Adding transparency to an image

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below image in a container. Is there a way to make the actual image itself more transparent? Right now it is blocking the text that I will overlay on top.

```
 return Consumer<UserModel>(
      builder: (context, model, _) => Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.8), // <-------------
            image: DecorationImage(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/pngguru.com-id-bnwsh.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: check out this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612599/make-boxdecoration-image-faded-transparent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make BoxDecoration image faded/transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612599/make-boxdecoration-image-faded-transparent)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Opacity widget and wrap it around your image.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html