# How to bend / crook a Flutter widget? (non-affine widget render transform)

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

Let's say you have some flutter widget, for example, a [`TabBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html). It is rendered in a rectangular box. I need it to be rendered in an arc so that the text and the underline follow part of a circle (or better still, a bezier curve).

How can that be achieved?

This illustrates what I am trying to achieve - bent [`TabBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) widget:

[image]

Please note that in this case, the [`TabBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) bends following and an arc (edge of a circle). This is what I need immediately. However, in the future, I might need bending that follows the edge of an eclipse so a solution that allows it would be preferable.

Also, a solution that works for different widgets is preferred.

**IMPORTANT**: **I do NOT want to clip a curved shape of the widget**. The entire area of the widget should stay visible. Instead, I need to **bend the content** of the widget (=bend its render image).

Apologies for the bold font but without it, people will keep posting answers about how to clip a widget which is trivial in comparison and useless for my problem.

*An answer "this is currently not supported by Flutter" from authority (e.g. high reputation in Flutter tag or Flutter a team member) will also be accepted.*

Comment: To prevent answers that would suggest clipping an arc of the widget: The entire area of the widget needs to be visible while the content of the widget(its render image) is bent.

Comment: It could be helpful if you post a picture of what you want to achieve, this way it would also prevent answers suggesting clipping.

Comment: @user1032613 Great idea. Will have added design file detail.

Comment: @user1032613 You were wrong :( It did not help, people are still posting clipping answers...

Comment: lol, sad... what you are looking for, is a transformation matrix to feed into the `Transform` widget. I don't have time right now to derive it using pen and paper, and I'm not aware of any automatic tool to generate that... I did upvote your question tho, hopefully someone can provide a matrix for you.

Comment: @user1032613 I do not think you are right. As far as I know, the `Transform` widget only supports *affine transforms* (move, scale, rotate, and combinations...). However, affine transform cannot *bend* the object (straight lines will always stay strait). That is why my question is so challenging... If a `Transform` widget was all I needed, I would not ask in the first place. And thank you for an upvote.

Comment: A 3x3 matrix is sufficient to linearly transform a 3D object. Transformations in Flutter allow a 4x4 matrix, so it should be enough to cover all 3D transformations, affine or not. For non-affine transformations, you should work in homogeneous coordinates and figure out a suitable matrix with the additional dimension.

Comment: Re the original question, I'm pretty sure that kind of transformation is not supported by Flutter but I'm not an authority (I would love to be proven wrong). Interestingly, the screenshot doesn't portray what I think OP asked, as the text and the image are not bended. You can definitely build the existing screenshot in Flutter with a combination of different widgets (basically building the tab bar yourself, with CustomPaint etc which is no quick task).

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because we agree that a 3x3 matrix cannot do the required transformation but I still don't see how a 4x4 matrix (the extra dimension typically used for translation) can bend the object following a curve (a function). If you can provide some kind of link or source I'd love to learn new math, thanks!

Comment: @mike I did a quick google search, it looks like this answer from a few years ago on our sister website is saying pretty much the same thing: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/578592/83011

Comment: What about drawing it by yourself using CustomPainter? I am sure Transform, even if 4x4, all transform lines to lines (instead of curves).

Comment: @user1032613 I truly appreciate your effort but, in projective transformations, lines map to lines (see youtu.be/uyYKPUZg3og). What OP wants is to map lines to curves, which is not possible because there isn't enough information in a 4x4 matrix to begin with. To solve this problem the traditional way we need to break each line into smaller lines and transform those with matrices I believe. This image may help you visualize what OP wants to do with straight lines (shorturl.at/lmJW7). Thank you for your time, I learned a lot!

Comment: I have searched through skia, the engine under Flutter, and it does not have such ability. Thus, it is highly likely that there is no highly performant solution (except drawing via CustomPainter by yourself)

Comment: @mike Ah, that clears it up a bit for me as well, thank you so much for the discussion. So to get curves, we must divide an image into smaller areas and transform each area? But if we divide it into finite smaller parts (like 10x10 grids) how can we make sure it's "smooth" when stitching? BTW, your second link (shorten URL) is no longer valid.

Comment: Yes, when deforming raster images we can only interpolate stretched (or compressed) pixels. For example here https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/178655i04DD47E33D07E385/image-size/original?v=mpbl-1&px=-1 if we moved a vertex, the texture mapped would have to stretch to fill the new area. I hope that makes sense. Don't mind the previous dead link.

Comment: I recommend using vector graphics (Lottie animations for tab switching, etc.) as a workaround and obviously, this is not an answer to the question. (If you don't get a proper and easy to implement answer in time.)
And vector graphics also support bent text, elliptical/circular, etc (all the things you require) and flutter has one solid implementation (a package that I know of) https://rive.app.

Comment: @user1032613 To cut the discussion short, mike is right fo course. Even if it was 100x100 transform matrix somehow, it would still map lines to lines again. Stating otherwise without being able to provide an example only spams the discussion here. Comments unfortunately cannot be downvoted but please stop it...

Comment: @mike What do you mean by 'the tab bar is not bent on thy screenshot'? It clearly is (although just a little). Look at the active tab underline, that's not a straight line, and also the text is bent a bit.

Comment: @PhaniRithvij This is actually a great idea! Care to make it an answer perhaps?

Comment: @Rasto Oh I didn't notice the text was bent too, my bad! I was thrown off by the profile pic (which could just be stacked so it wouldn't bend even if the tab bar was bent).

Comment: @Rasto my comment alone won't make for a good answer without a working example and it isn't trivial either as we'll have to implement a custom TabBar implementation using rive animations. I'll try to work on a basic prototype and post an answer, then you can decide if it's worth the effort to go this way.

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Thanks, I think other readers will also appreciate such an option... The other roads suggested are not straightforward either so this might be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

#### One approach: Use a `CustomPaint` to draw lines/areas/etc freely

You can use a [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) to draw whatever curved lines, areas, etc freely. Therefore, you can definitely achieve your goal - since they are nothing but curved lines, areas with curved edges, rotated texts, etc.
That will take a bit of work, but if you encapsulate it well enough, it is not that hard to implement. For example, draw a Path with filled red area, then draw a white arc, then draw several texts with calculated rotations, etc. Sounds like you can do that within maybe hundreds of lines. If you find difficulty implementing this please comment and I will explain.

#### Another approach: Hack `Canvas` such that the call to `drawLine` becomes indeed calls to `drawPath`, etc.

You may do the following to allow bend/crook for *any widget* (and their combination, of course), but this may need a bit of engineering. You can make your own `Canvas`, say, `class BendCanvas implements Canvas {}`. The `BendCanvas.drawLine`, for example, has an implementation of `Canvas.drawPath` with a curved path cooresponding to the input "line". Similar things hold for drawing rectangles, etc. Then you need to hack Flutter's painting logic, such that it takes in your own BendCanvas instead of the original canvas. This is a universal solution, and it is much more efficient (less code) if you plan to have a *lot* of bend UI; but if only on bend TabBar, maybe use the first approach.

#### As for the bend text

In the two approaches above, we have mainly described how you draw the bended rectangle (i.e. draw an arbitrary shaped widget). As for bending text, see: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16477 , which is still an open issue.

#### Remarks

It is not possible using transformations. As explained in the comments, you already see `Transform` does not work - it is affine or perspective, which, by definition, will not bend. Then what about other transforms? After some research there seems to be none. Then, what about looking under the scene. We know Flutter uses Skia under it to draw the UI with high performance, then let us search through Skia. However, it does not provide any transformations like bending. So there seems no use.

<sub>P.S. I am not that high reputation in Flutter tag, but I did answer >100 Flutter questions (including [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612599/make-boxdecoration-image-faded-transparent/64726479#64726479) dig-into-source-code style ones), and have developed >100k lines of Flutter code in the production app.</sub>

Comment: Finally some useful answer. Yes, unfortunately, I need the text to be bent as well. Any ideas there? Especially the with the third option, can it bend text? Also, I expect this to be one of my most popular questions in a few years. Therefore, as you answer might be the accepted one perhaps you want to shorten it a bit (remove description of the options that do not work) for it to be easier to read for future readers?

Comment: @Rasto subsection title added to be clear to read; let me have a search at bend text.

Comment: @Rasto a section of bending text is added. though that is still an open issue.

Comment: @Rasto This https://developers.mews.com/flutter-how-to-draw-text-along-arc/ was mentioned in the linked skia issue for curved text support in one of the comments. This answer along with this tutorial could work for you.